# Extjs Filter Row

Tags: extjs

I need to implement filter in extjs grid . In grid, first row of each column will function as filter. The functionality of filter that has Excel . Does anyone see example of this ?

For example if I show all stocks and trade dates of portfolio , I need to show in first column 
all the available stocks and available trade dates.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level you will need to populate a combobox with the available values for each of the columns, position them inside the grid and listen for the change/select event on the boxes to apply the 'store.filter' function to the main grid store.

I'm not aware of a plugin for this functionality out of the box.